# Python lib to Read a Flash swf Format File

Tags: python, flash

I'm interested in using Python to hack on the data in Flash swf files.  There is good [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/) available on the format of swf files, and I am considering writing my own Python lib to parse that data out using the standard Python [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) lib.

Does anybody know of a Python project that already does this?  I would also be interested in any available solutions that use Perl, Ruby, Haskell, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, unless you're doing it for fun (in which case, go for it!), why not use [Ming](http://www.libming.org/)? It supposedly has python wrappers...

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I remember hearding about Ming ages ago for use in PHP, but I didn't realize it did Python as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found another option in [SWF Tools](http://www.swftools.org/).  They provide a Python wrapper that supports generating SWF files in Python.

I'm not sure if either SWF Tools or Ming actually supports parsing in and modifying an existing swf file, however.  Both seem geared more towards generating swf files from scratch.