# Is it posible to hook a .swf and call it's functions with python? If so, how?

Tags: python, flash, hook

I have a .swf file that is running, I want to be able to call its internal function and modify/fetch its variable values.

How can I do this with python?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656704/python-lib-to-read-a-flash-swf-format-file

Comment: What functionality are you trying to implement?  Maybe there is another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in theory anything is possible, I don't see how you in any reasonable way can inspect the running state of a Flash program from Python.

It might be possible if Flash have some sort of debug mode, where you can attach to the process and inspect it that way. I don't know if it does. But look into Flash debuggers and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it's possible to do it with Python,but you have to hack the swf first,this might not be what Python can do easily.